# How to reference an Object library in VBA Excel when the installed version may vary between different users?

Tags: excel, vba, late-binding, object-library

I need to use a ChemDrawCtl object in one of my projects. So far I have used early binding by referencing the library "CD ChemDraw 20.0 Object Library" which have worked well so far. However, I have now been forced to make the code more portable and the installed version of this object library may differ between different users. I have found a "dirty" way to accomplish this via late binding, but it is, so to say, very non-elegant. Is there a better, more correct way to accomplish this? Example code:

```
Option Explicit

Function NewChemDrawCtl() As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Static v As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    If v = 0 Then
        For i = 50 To 12 Step -1
            Set NewChemDrawCtl = CreateObject("ChemDrawControl" & i & ".ChemDrawCtl")
            If TypeName(NewChemDrawCtl) = "ChemDrawCtl" Then
                v = i
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Else
        Set NewChemDrawCtl = CreateObject("ChemDrawControl" & v & ".ChemDrawCtl")
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: What you describe as the "dirty way" (late binding) is in fact the standard way to handle different users having different versions of a library.

Comment: Isn't there any better way to find what version of the object that is available except for looping 40 versions? I know I could access all the available references but that requires "Allow excel access to the object model" which isn't typically the case.

Comment: _Isn't there any better way to find what version of the object that is available..._ no, there isn't

Comment: It *might* be possible to get that information from the registry, but that would depend on the user's permissions. If the GUID for the object is the same across versions, as it often is, you could use that instead.

Comment: Ok Great! I didn't believe that GUID was kept between versions.  I need to check if that is the case.